# Why Does SQL Server OPENQUERY To Oracle Return Different Column Types On SQL Server 2016 to 2008

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server, odbc

I have two SQL Server Instances on the same machine, one 2008 and one 2016. Both instances have a linked server connection to the same Oracle 12 Server.

If I run the following query 2008 returns 1.23 as a VARCHAR but 2016 returns it as a float

```
SELECT * INTO #tst FROM OPENQUERY(JOHPROD,'SELECT 1.23 FROM dual')
SELECT t.Name,* FROM tempdb.sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.types t ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tst');
```

[image: VarcharType]

[image]

Both instances are pointing to the same Oracle server and both using the same Oracle ODBC driver.

Both linked servers have this same definition...

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'ORAPROD', @srvproduct=N'Oracle', @provider=N'OraOLEDB.Oracle', @datasrc=N'ORAPROD'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'ORAPROD',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'ORAUSER',@rmtpassword='########'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORAPROD', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORAPROD', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORAPROD', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORAPROD', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORAPROD', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORAPROD', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORAPROD', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORAPROD', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORAPROD', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=NULL
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORAPROD', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORAPROD', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORAPROD', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORAPROD', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

Any idea why these would return different types?

Comment: Are you using the same provider in the linked server setup? Can you please post the linked server definitions ?

Comment: Added definition to post. Both use the same provider

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behaviour has changed in recent updates. See 
[FIX: The value of NUMBER type is truncated when you select data from an Oracle-linked server by using OLE DB provider](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3051993/fix-the-value-of-number-type-is-truncated-when-you-select-data-from-an)

> After you apply this fix, NUMBER values with unknown precision/scale
>   are treated as double values with OLE DB provider. If the precision is
>   important and the range of the values is not large enough, you can
>   enable the new Trace Flag 7314 that would start treating such values
>   as numeric (38, 10).

However I'm a bit surprised you are getting a `float` instead of a `double` \ `numeric` since that seems to contradict the article somewhat, so I'm not sure it explains your exact situation.